# Simplifying boolean expressions help (tried rules but confused)

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```
ABD+ABC+ABCD
```

I understand that AB is the common factor so I think it becomes:

```
AB(D+C+CD)
AB(D(1+c)+C)
AB(C+D)
```

or

```
AB(D+C+CD)
```

use commutative law? (i think thats what its called)
    AB(CD+D+C)
    AB(C+D)

Please help, I'm very confused with this

Answer (score 1):

this is the last step. AB(CD+D+C) => AB(C+D(1+C)) => AB(C+D)

A(1+B)== A(true) .1+B IS always true. this could be thought as (true or expression) which is always true.

Think of the truth table of OR operator.

A     B   value

0     0  0

0    1   1

1    0  1

1  1  1

here we have value =1 for all the cases where one of the exp =1. Thats all you need.

Commutative law states that A+B=B+A.

This is because truth table of A+B is same as B+A.

Comment: how did you get to A(1+B).1+B? Sorry for this question as I guess its simple but I'm new to this.

Comment: here is the last step. AB(CD+D+C) => AB(C+D(1+C)) => AB(C+D)

Comment: ty yash, you helped a lot